# How does one convert complex SQL queries into Zend_Db_Select statements?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

The MySQL website has an [excellent tutorial](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) on storing hierarchal data in a database. I'm trying to write the query that returns a node's immediate children. I don't want to just copy/paste the query from the MySQL website, because I'm trying to work on this in a database agnostic manner.

This is the query I'm trying to Zend_Db_Select-ify

```
SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
    nested_category AS parent,
    nested_category AS sub_parent,
    (
        SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
        FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent
        WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.name = 'PORTABLE ELECTRONICS'
        GROUP BY node.name
        ORDER BY node.lft
    )AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
    AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

Comment: +1 just for the link to the tutorial!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try spliting your query into two `Zend_Db_Select` statements - parent query and subquery. You can use `Zend_Db_Select` object as param of `from()` method, like below:

```
$mainQuery = $db->select();
$mainQuery->from('user');

$sub = $db->select();
$sub->from('company');

$mainQuery->from(array('subquery' => $sub));
```

And you will get that kind of query:

```
SELECT `user`.*, `sub`.* FROM `user` 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT `company`.* FROM `company`
    ) AS `sub`
```

As you see, it automatically adds `INNER JOIN` when you add second `from()` - but I think, it's possible to rewrote your query to user joins instead of multi from syntax. So you should use `joinInner()` method, because then you can specify join condition as second param of it.

Notice, that subquery is similar to main query, so you could build main query, clone it as subquery, and thanks to `Zend_Db_Select` possibilities remove unnecessary parts (`reset()` method) and replace them:

```
$mainQuery = $db->select(); //and rest
$subQuery = clone $mainQuery;
$subQuery->reset(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
$subQuery->where(); // and add valid conditions for subquery
```

Comment: +1 -- Is there an easier way to specify the AS clause in the `from` besides calling `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::quoteIdentifier` ?

Comment: Saying 'specify' you mean sanitizing? If yes, when you creating a subquery you can use named bind parameters, for e.g. `:nodeName` and bind it at the moment of query execution - as second parameter of `fetchAll()` method from db adapter.

Comment: @singles: No, I mean if one of the fields on my table is called "Left" (instead of "Lft"), which is a SQL reserved word. Therefore it must be escaped. For example, on MySQL it needs to turn into \`Left\`, while on MSSQL it needs to be [[Left]].

Comment: @Billy ONeal Ohhh, in this case I don't know another way than `quoteIdentifier`, sorry :/

Comment: @Singles: I mean just like Zend_Db_Select already does. I.e. if you do `$x->select()->from('MyTable', array('Left'));` it gets escaped.

Comment: Part of your main `Zend_Db_Select` query is another query of that type. They act the same, so if you specify columns like above, they should be escaped.   I tried to Zend_Db_Select-ify (as exercise) your query and got something like that - http://pastebin.com/3WkYFyPk. I don't have original database to check it, but maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just paste in the query directly like this

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
        FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent,
        nested_category AS sub_parent,
        (
            SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
            FROM nested_category AS node,
            nested_category AS parent
            WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
            AND node.name = 'PORTABLE ELECTRONICS'
            GROUP BY node.name
            ORDER BY node.lft
        )AS sub_tree
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
        AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
    GROUP BY node.name
    ORDER BY node.lf");
```

Be sure to use `quote()` to input any of your own parameters into this query.

This is a bit of a cheat and isn't something I have resorted to yet.