# Zend_Db_Select with variable assignment and subqueries

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I'm having a rough time figuring out where to start with getting this query into a Zend_Db_Select. I have never worked with variables assignment and subqueries in Zend:

```
SELECT
    @current_continent := stats_geo_continent.id AS `continent_id`,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(code) from stats_geo_country WHERE stats_geo_country.continent = @current_continent) AS `group`,
    stats_geo_country.code
FROM
    stats_geo_continent
INNER JOIN
    stats_geo_country ON stats_geo_country.continent = stats_geo_continent.id;
```

Comment: If it is not needed, maybe use a $db->query(). You could also create a view in your database and make a model for it. I think it would be faster and more efficient than using Db_select.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be possible when you use `Zend_Db_Expr` for your variable assignments. For subgqueries you can use second `Zend_Db_Select` object as a part of main object - maybe [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883583/how-does-one-convert-complex-sql-queries-into-zend-db-select-statements/4884493#4884493) will help you.